# Only show one copy of histogram for shared weights in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a model that shares hidden layer weights between several subgraphs. It's easy to accomplish the sharing via `tf.variable_scope(.., reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)`, however, the `tf.summary.histogram` results in multiple identical plots on Tensorboard, because it's written next to the `tf.get_variable(..)` code that creates those weights. Is there a way in python to know whether a variable has already been created, and use that to skip the histogram creation in the graph? Alternatively, is there an analogue of AUTO_REUSE for name_scope? Thanks!

Best,
  John

Comment: It's always useful to add code if you have one

Comment: @Sharky: Sorry but the code is pretty lengthy and somewhat proprietary.